What is the best way to unit test private methods?
I haven't really found a good method on how to apart from just having the tests module directly in the code that they test for, but I find this to increase the size of whatever module too much and overall just sucks for readability (in my opinion)

If your only issue is the line count of the file being tested, you don't need to define the module in-line. It's just like any other module declaration - you can make a tests.rs file instead.

You didn't understand what testing means. Don't test methods, test the component behaviour. The behaviour is described by its public methods. A test is not different than the production code that uses the component. It must not know anything about the component's implementation.

As a genuine question, how are you meant to test behavior that may not happen everytime a component is ran?
For example, lets say I have some sort of functionality that runs every few seconds and if something happens remotely then we will do something else, but this other functionality is required to be tested due to variability in whatever sense
Are you just meant to seperate that specific branch of functionality (lets say move it to a new struct) and then test it individually?
(I apologize if this is pretty badly phrased, I don't really have much time right now so it was rushed)
